# Compiling and running a java program with complex file structure from the commandline

Tags: java, linux, javac

Trying to compile and run my java program from the commandline that is set up a bit weird.  The file structure is as follows:

```
[ROOT]/
|
|____libs/
|    |____myExtraJar.jar
|     
|____src/
     |____main/
          |____com/
               |____example/
                    |____myClass.java
```

The package is defined at the top of the java file as

```
package com.example;
```

I am able to compile the program fine (I think) while in the root folder, using

```
javac -classpath "/libs/myExtraJar.jar" src/main/com/example/*.java
```

I don't get any compilation errors (such the ones that occur if I leave off the classpath) and I can see that .class files are being created in the com/example/ folder.  However, I can't find any way to run the compiled program.  Running

```
java src/main/com/example/myClass
```

results in the message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.com.example.myClass
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you have a file structure like this (which is called the Standard Directory Layout, by the way), you're usually using Maven or Gradle to manage your build, and the `src/main` isn't part of the package.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, this project exists as a remnant of an old Android Studio project and uses the original file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the classpath when you run it, and you also need to use the fully-qualified classname. Like,

```
java -cp "libs/myExtraJar.jar:src/main" com.example.myClass
```

Comment: This was the issue, thanks so much!  Will accept the answer as correct as soon as it will let me.

Answer (score 0):

Elliot is right. More precisely, you need to add the *build directory* to your classpath. It is the directory containing your `*.class` files, and is sometimes named `target/`.

```
$ java -cp "target:lib/myExtraJar.jar" com.example.myClass
```

Moreover, `src/main/com/example/myClass` should be `com.example.myClass`, which is the *fully-qualified class name*. See http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/ for details of the `java` command.